# Why my controller not working in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am working like a social media application... but in my controller last else if not working for status upload. but file and video uload working nicely. what is the correct format for this. here is my controller

public function getclass(Request $request)
{

```
if (Input::has('post_comment'))
{
    $status=Input::get('post_comment');
    $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
    $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

    $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
       'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
       'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
       'status_id'=>$status

        ]);
    Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
    return redirect(route('class'));
}

if(Input::has('status-text'))
{
    $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
    $rules = [
        'status_text'=>'required|string',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


    if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
    {
        $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
            $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
            $userStatus -> type = 1;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();

            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
    }
    else if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $userStatus = new Status();
        $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
        $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
        $userStatus -> type = 2;
        $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $userStatus -> save();

        Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
    else if($validator->fails())
    {
        $userStatus = new Status();
        $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
        $userStatus -> type = 3;
        $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $userStatus -> save();

        Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
}


    return view('class',[
    'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
    ]);
```

}

In this controller this code not working

```
else if($validator->fails())
{
    $userStatus = new Status();
    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
    $userStatus -> type = 3;
    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userStatus -> save();

    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
    return redirect(route('class'));
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting??

Comment: there is no error.....else if($validator->fails())
{
    $userStatus = new Status();
    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
    $userStatus -> type = 3;
    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userStatus -> save();

    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
    return redirect(route('class'));
} this part not working...

Comment: are you trying to save record to database if the validation **failed**

Comment: yes sir... but if i use this                                                                       else
{
    $userStatus = new Status();
    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
    $userStatus -> type = 3;
    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userStatus -> save();

    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
    return redirect(route('class'));
} still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That portion of code will never get executed. Because the `else if` block above your code i.e this part

```
else if ($validator->fails())
{
    $userStatus = new Status();
    $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
    $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
    $userStatus -> type = 2;
    $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userStatus -> save();

    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
    return redirect(route('class'));
}
```

has kind of block it. You are using the same condition in both the `else if` block. This means if the above `else if` condition fails then the other will also fail. And the `validation rules` you are using in both conditions are also same.

Comment: Actually you don't need that part of code. The above `else if` block will do what you are trying to achieve with that code. Only the difference is `video_url`. So remove that `else if` part and replace `$userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];` with `$userStatus -> video_url = ($request['video_url'] !=null) ? $request['video_url'] : "" ;` in the above code and c if it helps.

Comment: also try changing `else if ($validator->fails())` to `else if ($validator->passes())`

Comment: if this helped you then please accept my post. Btw I am glad you found your solution

Comment: Actually how can i accept your post i dont no the process. please give me the process i will must accept your post..sir

Comment: click on the grey check mark near the answer and that's it